# Qt Tab Order with Return Key

Tags: c++, qt

I Have a Form with several LineEdits and other Elements and want to jump from one to the next by pressing the **return** key.
I find Return key instead of/additional to the tab key more user friendly.

I can probably do it if i use `returnPressed()` and `setFocus()` but i hope there is a better more elegant solution for this.

1. Is there a way to modify the built in tab order to also work with
   return?
2. If not, what are the best ways to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the event handler. ( `QEvent` )

Example from the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/eventsandfilters.html)

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
    if (ke->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
        // special tab handling here
        return true;
    }
    } else if (event->type() == MyCustomEventType) {
    MyCustomEvent *myEvent = static_cast<MyCustomEvent *>(event);
    // custom event handling here
    return true;
    }

    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

It's easily adjustable to any key.

For example if return is pressed simulate a tab key press event.

Comment: Although this is not incorrect, it would be simpler to override [QWidget::keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) instead of QWidget::event.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it is more efficient to override [QWidget::keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent)

Some code:

```cpp
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override;
```

```cpp
  void MyWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Return){
      this->focusNextChild();
    }
  }
```